# How to get the "for=" property of an HTML <legend> element

Tags: javascript

I am writing a chrome extension and using javascript to search DOM elements.
I've come across a page that has `<legend>` elements that look something like this:

```
<legend for="contact_email">Contact Email</legend>
```

My code is doing the following:

```
let legends = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('legend'));
console.log('# Legends found: ' + legends.length);
for (let l of legends ) {
    console.log("Legend for= attribute: " + l.htmlFor + " );
}
```

This htmlFor is always undefined.
This works for `<label>`.
Is there another way to get the for= attribute for `<legend>`?

Comment: The HTML you're looking at is simply wrong; `for` is not a recognized attribute on `<legend>` elements. You can get the value, but you have to use `getAttribute()`.

Comment: Legend only has [global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) and `for` is not one.

Comment: You probably wanted to use `label` tags. Label has the `for` attribute.

Comment: Note that [`legend` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend) are supposed to act as captions for their parent `fieldset` elements. [`fieldset`s typically wrap multiple form elements and their `label`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset).

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

```js
let legends = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('legend'));
console.log('# Legends found: ' + legends.length);
for (let l of legends ) {
    console.log("Legend for= attribute: " + l.getAttribute('for') + " );
}
```

Note- Pointy's comment is correct in that `<legend>` does not support the attribute `for`; it only supports [Global Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes)

Comment: Thank you.  This will get me by.